# When formula copies down move row reference down one row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Issue: When I copy the Excel formula it does exactly what I ask, it copies it. However I want it to add a row so if the formula was `=A1` I want it to change to `=A2` and so forth. Code:

```
    Worksheets("Portal").Cells(i, j).Formula = Worksheets("Portal").Cells(7, j).Formula
```

One option would be to do this row by row and put the formulas in the VB but I would prefer to avoid that if I can. Details:

i = Loop function for each new row
j = Loop function for each column/cell

the number after the i is the column i.e. A is 1 and so forth
7 in the later part of the formula is the row I am duplicating down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use the R1C1 version:

```
Worksheets("Portal").Cells(i, j).FormulaR1C1 = Worksheets("Portal").Cells(7, j).FormulaR1C1
```

This then also means that you can assign the same formula to the entire column without looping.

Comment: Each column has a different formula, does that stop the above being, in this instance, valid? Also does it make A1 change to A2? I'll have a play of course when back at a PC

Comment: No, it's still valid. You don't have to loop the rows, but you do need to loop the columns. Unless `i` starts at 8, in which case you can just use `FillDown`.

Comment: Row 8 is essentially row 1 i.e. row 8 needs duplicating down. I am not going to make it male tonight so I will try tomorrow now. Thanks